# How does one find/list equivalence classes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Can someone explain how I would find/list the equivalence classes (And number of equivalence classes) of these two examples?

Example 1: A is the set of all possible strings of 3 or 4 letters in alphabet
{A, B, C, D}, and (x, y) ∈ R if and only if x and y have the same first letter and the same third letter.

Here I can gather that x and y must both have letters (same)_(same)_ but I am not sure where to go from here.

EDIT: After thinking a bit I think the equivalence classes are A_B_, A_C_, A_D_, B_A_, B_C_, B_D_, C_A_, C_B_, C_D_, D_A_, D_B_, D_C_. Is this correct and am I missing any?

Example 2: A is the power set of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, and
(x, y) ∈ R if and only if x ∩ {1, 3, 5} = y ∩ {1, 3, 5}.

On this one I have gathered that X and Y must both have the same subset of {1, 3, 5) But I dont know where to go from here.

Comment: What do you mean by “find”? Do you mean just to describe them, or to count the number of things in each class, or what?

Comment: List the classes and count the number of total classes. Sorry I will clarify my title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to (1) seems almost correct to me. My method: think of what property all the elements of one class would have: they all have the same first letter in their string, and also they have the same third letter. So a *class* is described by (first letter, third letter), such as “A_B_”. My only objection is that ordinarily, a “string from the alphabet $\Omega$” can have repeated letters, just like an English word. So in my book, the string “AAAA” would be allowed by your definition, and your answer would also need to admit repeated letters, I think.

For (2), think of what all the things in one particular equivalence class have in common. The setup is a bit more abstract, making the question a little harder, but I think that if you think about things a bit more, you can do it.

Comment: A_A_, A_B_, A_C_, A_D_, B_A_, B_B_, B_C_, B_D_, C_A_, C_B_, C_C_, C_D_, D_A_, D_B_, D_C_, D_D_ would be all the classes for question one then? And also sorry to bug you again but is that how I "name" a class or is there a certain format for naming a class?

Comment: I think if you count the number of classes (and I agree with your enumeration now), you’ll get a clue of how to describe them.

Comment: 16 total... I don't see what you are referring to though :s I'm trying to learn relations on my own so I'm not sure what proper terms are, but something like {x|(x,y)∈R, x_x_ ~ y_y_} might be correct?

Comment: Or actually I think it might be something like 

A1 = A_A_ and 

A2 = A_B_

ect?

Comment: Well, that’s if you need to name them. Ordinarily, that’s not necessary.